# Can't create optional prefix of the token

Tags: antlr4

I have built this to recognize query like this `FILTER METHOD=="GET" STATUS=="200" RETURN"*"`. Now I need to change it to be able to recognize this: `FILTER METHOD=="GET" STATUS=="200" RETURN"*"` and `FILTER METHOD==GET STATUS==200 RETURN*`. So it is optional if there are quoutation marks or not but all of the tokens must have same pattern (quotation marks or not). This is working in all combinations with or without quotation marks but it is not how it supposed to be. I've tried a lot of possibilities but no luck...

```
request: 'FILTER' expr* 'RETURN' num;
expr: KEY OP value;
value: ((STRING|NUM)+);
num: NUM;

NUM: (('0'..'9')+|'*');
KEY: ('IP' | 'DATETIME' | 'METHOD' | 'VERSION' | 'STATUS');
OP: ('!=' | '==');
STRING: ((('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+|':'|'/'|'.')+);
WHITESPACE: ((' '|'\\t')+) -> skip;
EOL: ('\\n') -> skip;
ESC: ('"') -> skip;
```

Any ideas how to do it without changing grammar a lot?

Comment: How can you successfully parse something with `"GET"` while you have this: `ESC: ('"') -> skip;`?

Comment: I suppose it's because quotation marks are not included in string definition. Little bit unclear but it is working fine and without any errors.

Comment: But you said you wanted to recognise `FILTER METHOD=="GET"`, which contains quotes... By skipping them, you'd make input like this also valid:  `""""""FILTER METHOD"=="""GET"""""""""""""""""`

Comment: And `value` matches multiple`STRING`s and `NUM`s? So `STATUS  == 123 str 424242 *` is valid? And also: this in a lexer rule: `'\\n'` matched a backslash followed by an `'n'` character. It does not match a line break.  Perhaps you need to take a step back and do an ANTLR tutorial before slapping things together.

Comment: At first I had to skip all quotation marks but later had to change that to recognise both with or without. I've done it in a different way at the end but thank you very much.